# Getting screwy results from NSDateComponentsFormatter

Tags: objective-c, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I recently learned about the new-to-iOS8 class NSDateComponentsFormatter. It lets you generate time strings for time-spans rather than dates. Pretty cool. I decided to tinker with it, and wrote some test code that creates various time-spans and logs the output. Here's my code (English and French output)

```
  NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
  
  
  NSDateComponentsFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
  formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleFull;
  formatter.calendar = gregorian;
  
  formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitYear + NSCalendarUnitMonth + NSCalendarUnitDay;
  
  NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
  for (int years = 1; years <= 10; years++)
  {
    int days = arc4random_uniform(10);
    components.year = years;
    components.month = 3;
    components.day = days;
    NSString* outputString = [formatter stringFromDateComponents: components];
    NSLog(@"For %02d years %02d days, Date Components string = '%@'", years, days, outputString);
  }

  NSLocale *franceLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier: @"fr_FR"];
  gregorian.locale = franceLocale;
  formatter.calendar = gregorian;

  NSLog(@"--------------- French. --------------");
  for (int years = 1; years <= 10; years++)
  {
    int days = arc4random_uniform(10) ;

    components.year = years;
    components.day = days;

    NSString* outputString = [formatter stringFromDateComponents: components];
    NSLog(@"For %02d years %02d days, Date Components string = '%@'", years, days, outputString);
  }
```

(I don't log the months value since it's fixed.)

Here's the output:

```
For 01 years 00 days, Date Components string = '1 year, 3 months'
For 02 years 05 days, Date Components string = '2 years, 3 months, 5 days'
For 03 years 01 days, Date Components string = '3 years, 3 months'
For 04 years 06 days, Date Components string = '4 years, 3 months, 6 days'
For 05 years 07 days, Date Components string = '5 years, 3 months, 7 days'
For 06 years 02 days, Date Components string = '6 years, 3 months, 1 day'
For 07 years 04 days, Date Components string = '7 years, 3 months, 4 days'
For 08 years 02 days, Date Components string = '8 years, 3 months, 2 days'
For 09 years 08 days, Date Components string = '9 years, 3 months, 8 days'
For 10 years 03 days, Date Components string = '10 years, 3 months, 2 days'
--------------- French. --------------
For 01 years 02 days, Date Components string = '1 année, 3 mois et 2 jours'
For 02 years 02 days, Date Components string = '2 années, 3 mois et 2 jours'
For 03 years 05 days, Date Components string = '3 années, 3 mois et 5 jours'
For 04 years 03 days, Date Components string = '4 années, 3 mois et 3 jours'
For 05 years 04 days, Date Components string = '5 années, 3 mois et 4 jours'
For 06 years 04 days, Date Components string = '6 années, 3 mois et 4 jours'
For 07 years 04 days, Date Components string = '7 années, 3 mois et 3 jours'
For 08 years 08 days, Date Components string = '8 années, 3 mois et 8 jours'
For 09 years 05 days, Date Components string = '9 années, 3 mois et 5 jours'
For 10 years 02 days, Date Components string = '10 années, 3 mois et 2 jours'
```

Note that in several cases the output days value in the output of the formatter does not match the days value fed into it.

Does anybody know what's going wrong here? This looks an awful lot like an OS/framework bug to me.

### EDIT:

I ran my test code in a Mac app, under OS X version 10.10.5 Is anybody else running 10.10.5 and can they try it?

I also got one wrong answer against the 8.1 sim. (For input value 07 years, 3 months, 06 days, Date Components string = '7 years, 3 months, 5 days')

Comment: System info? I don't reproduce this in a handful of tries running on OS X or on the 8.4 or 9.2 simulators.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the system locale and calendar?

Comment: System locale is US English. System calendar is Gregorian. I'm running this code in OS X under 10.10.5

Comment: If I put the same code in an iOS simulator project it seems to run flawlessly against 9.2, but I got 1 wrong string running this code on the iOS 8.1. sim. Beginning to look like its an OS-specific bug.

Comment: I am seeing weird results like yours on 10.10.x and not on 10.11.x. May be a bug. May also be that some things were unspecified and the behavior was valid, just unexpected. See if filling out more properties of the components or formatter helps. For example, the components can also have a `calendar` or `timeZone`.

Comment: The way I read the docs you pick the units you care about and it generate a string describing the time span in those units. I can't see how a wrong number of days is valid.

Comment: It's looking more and more like an OS X 10.10/iOS 8 bug. Apple is TERRIBLE about fixing bugs in previous OS releases. Once a new major release is out, I think we're stuck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the iOS 8.x and Mac OS 10.10 version of the `NSDateComponentsFormatter` is buggy. I get (intermittent!) different, wrong results for some dates in those OS versions, but correct results from the latest OS versions.

Sigh...

Comment: `NSDateComponentsFormatter` is `NSCalendar` based. It considers also daylight saving time changes.